# $f(x)=|x|⋅x$ what is the inverse at $f^{−1}(x)$ if $x≥0$ and the inverse at $f^{−1}(x)$ if $x≤0.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

I tried this question and my only solution is that this is not possible  or is there another way to solve this?

$f(x) = x|x| $

(Q): What is the inverse at $f^{−1}(x)$ if $x ≥ 0$ and the inverse at $f^{−1}(x)$ if $x≤0$.

Comment: "*This is not possible*"  No, that is the incorrect result you should have arrived at.  Think about square roots.  If you want to build intuition, consider looking at the graph of the original function and see what happens if you reflect the graph over the line $y=x$.

Comment: Come on you should try again, or post your attempts so that we can know where your problem really lies in.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$f(x)=x^2$ if $x \ge 0$

and

$f(x)=-x^2$ if $x<0.$

Can you proceed ?